# Twilio - How to determine the length of a conference call?

Tags: python, twilio

I am creating an application that creates many conference rooms.  These rooms will have one expert/moderator that will talk to one or more people also in the conference room.  For billing, I need to be able to find the length of the conference call.  This time has to be from when the expert joins the conference room (if other people are in it) to when the last person (not the expert) leaves.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

Using the [Conferences list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference#list) may help you here. You can pull the conference details like this:

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "{{ account_id }}"
auth_token  = "{{ auth_token }}"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

# A list of conference objects with the properties described above
conferences = client.conferences.list()
```

Each conference will have a date_created and date_updated property that you could use to determine length. The documentation I linked to shows how to filter this conference list based on things like room name and status of the call.

If you need to get more precise based on participant than you can use the [participants resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant) to find out how long individual participants spent on the call.

Hope that helps!